# Usando bibliotecas .jar no embarcadero

Tags: delphi, jar, embarcadero

Boa tarde a todos

Pesquisando achei vários posts falado sobre o java2po e sua função de conversão de bibliotecas .jar para linguagem delphi. Consegui realizar a conversão de alguma bibliotecas que vou precisar, só que quando carrego os arquivos convertidos eles apresentam diversos erros "undeclared identifier".
Gostaria de ajuda na resolução desse problema e onde posso achar um modelo para me guiar sobre o uso dessas bibliotecas.

Agradeço muito a ajuda.